# Python: Getting all pairs and frequency of pairs in multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, list

my multi-dimensional list looks as follows:

```
    mylist = [[13, 41, 3, 23, 12, 16], [12, 32, 30, 49, 3, 18], 
              [34, 12, 14, 24, 35, 20], [29, 28, 12, 44, 13, 4],
              [31, 44, 6, 49, 5, 39]]
```

There are pairs (numbers with difference 1) in some of the lists. not in every list: (12,13) in the first list, (34,35) in the third list, (28,29) and (12,13) in the fourth.

What I want to have is to get all the found pairs which should be saved in a (sorted) list based on the frequency (ascending). In my case above, it would look like follows:

```
    fr_list = [[12,13],[12,13],[28,29],[34,35]]
```

I wrote the following code to find the pairs

```
    def find_pairs(lst, key):
            return [(a,b) for a,b in permutations(lst, 2) if a-b==key]
```

Then, I tried this:

```
    fr_list = [find_pairs(mylist,1) for x in mylist]
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
      File "<stdin>", line 2, in find_pairs
      File "<stdin>", line 2, in <listcomp>
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: why is `5, 6` not in the desired result?

Comment: Just forgotten!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is functionally correct, but your final list comprehension is incorrect. It should be `fr_list = [find_pairs(x,1) for x in mylist]`. In your case, you attempt to put a list of lists into your find_pairs function. However, changing `mylist` to `x` means you are iterating through each nested list, not the entire list of lists for every nested list.

Comment: Omg, I overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake here:

```
[find_pairs(mylist, 1) for x in mylist]
```

You passed the same original list everytime to the function and not the sublists. Hence, inside function when you do `if a-b==key`, `a` and `b` are lists.

Correcting this, you can use following code to obtain your desired output:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

def find_pairs(lst, key):
    return [(a, b) for a, b in permutations(lst, 2) if a - b == key]


mylist = [[13, 41, 3, 23, 12, 16], [12, 32, 30, 49, 3, 18], 
          [34, 12, 14, 24, 35, 20], [29, 28, 12, 44, 13, 4],
          [31, 44, 6, 49, 5, 39]]


temp_list = list(chain.from_iterable([find_pairs(x, 1) for x in mylist])) 
fr_list = sorted(temp_list, key=lambda x: temp_list.count(x), reverse=True)

print(fr_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how i would go about this:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat, chain

def find_diff(lst):
    srt = sorted(lst)
    return Counter((a, b) for a, b in zip(srt, srt[1:]) if b - a == 1)

pairs = sum((find_diff(item) for item in mylist), Counter())
# Counter({(12, 13): 2, (34, 35): 1, (28, 29): 1, (5, 6): 1})
res = tuple(
    chain.from_iterable(repeat(item, count) for item, count in pairs.most_common())
)
# ((12, 13), (12, 13), (34, 35), (28, 29), (5, 6))
```

it is more efficient to iterate over the sorted list if you are looking for a difference of `1`. then i store everything in [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects in order to efficiently find the most common.

the last part is a bit of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) magic that extracts the items and their multiplicity by frequency.

Comment: Your list is not sorted by frequency; it so happens to be correct in this case, because counter is sorted by order of insertion, and the most frequent items came first, but it will not work in the general case.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque ok, fixed it. thanks for pointing the mistake out.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use sorting to avoid comparing each pair with all other pairs, and `collections Counter` to aggregate the results:

Maybe something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_pairs(seq):
    s = sorted(seq)
    all_pairs = []
    for first, second in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]):
        if second - first == 1:
            all_pairs.append((first, second))
    return all_pairs

mylist = [[13, 41, 3, 23, 12, 16], [12, 32, 30, 49, 3, 18], 
              [34, 12, 14, 24, 35, 20], [29, 28, 12, 44, 13, 4],
              [31, 44, 6, 49, 5, 39]]

all_pairs = []
for seq in mylist:
    all_pairs += find_pairs(seq)
res = []
for pair, qtty in sorted([(k, v) for k, v in Counter(all_pairs).items()], key=lambda x: x[1])[::-1]:
    for _ in range(qtty):
        res.append(pair)

res
```

#### output:

```
[(12, 13), (12, 13), (5, 6), (28, 29), (34, 35)]
```

Comment: The approaches are indeed similar, but I took a look at your answer after I posted mine; this is where I saw the mistake, and commented. Have some good rep for your trouble @hiroprotagonist

Comment: yup, we agree on that! sorry again!